# using google script to use local client outlook to send email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, outlook

I'm trying to get my script to add information into a google sheet then I want it to open outlook with a body of text and the workers email prefilled based on what was entered into the sheet

so far I have the script putting the information into the sheet but i haven't been able to or found a way to get it to open outlook to send the email

this is my script so far

```
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Form')
      .addItem('add Item', 'addItem')
      .addToUi();
}

function addItem()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Add New Item');
  
}

function addNewItem(form_data)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Quoting');
  
  sheet.appendRow([form_data.first_name, form_data.last_name, form_data.email, form_data.Date]);
}
```

and this is the HTML that I'm using to add the info in

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="first name">Project</label>
    <input type='text' name='first_name' id="first_name" required="required"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Builder</label>
    <input type='text' name='last_name' id="last_name" required="required"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="email">Quoted by</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' id="email" required="required"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="Date">Due Date</label>
    <input type='text' name='Date' id="Date" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
    <button type="submit" class="action">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
    function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
     google.script.host.close();//close this dialogbox
    }
    );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

before anyone says to upload the files onto google drive and then attach after that, the company I'm doing this for had polices in place that mean I cannot do that (they only use their servers for storing documents)

can anyone help me figure this out

Comment: If you want to send the email using the same google account in which you have logged in, it is very simple. There are many examples which you can use.  Try : https://blog.gsmart.in/google-apps-script-send-html-email/

Comment: I know, I have done that with a couple of scripts already, what I want to do is when a button is pressed it opens outlook with the message ready to go so the worker can add attachments that our non-google drive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: using the script above and any additional code required, is it possible to have the script send an HTML email via Outlook instead of through gmail